# Simple model of (propositional) intuitionistic logic to recognize valid formulas

Tags: logic, model-theory, intuitionistic-logic

I noticed that when I want to know (or rather see/understand) whether some classical tautology is valid intuitionistically, I first try to replace each propositional variable by a finite union of open intervals on the real line $\mathbb R$, and see whether I can construct a counterexample in this way. I started to believe that this approach would always work, and found the following on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic):

> It can be shown that to recognize valid formulas, it is sufficient to consider a single Heyting algebra whose elements are the open subsets of the real line $\mathbb R$.

The reference for this statement is "Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism" by M. Sørensen and P. Urzyczyn, which contains the following theorem:

> 1. A formula $\varphi$ of length $n$ is valid iff it is valid in all Heyting algebras of cardinality at most $2^{2^n}$;
> 2. Let $\mathcal H$ be the algebra of all open subsets of a dense-in-itself metric space $V$ (for instance the algebra of all open subsets of $\mathbb R^2$). Then $\mathcal H \vDash \varphi$ iff $\varphi$ is valid.

This theorem is not sufficient for proving that my approach will always work, because it might be necessary to also consider open sets like the complement of the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set), or at least complements of countable closed sets with interesting limit points.

But if my approach would always work, then already the algebra $\mathcal H'$ of all unions of open intervals with integer end points of $\mathbb R$ should satisfy "$\mathcal H' \vDash \varphi$ iff $\varphi$ is valid". Is this true? If not, what is a simple counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, your approach does not always work. The formula $$\lnot\lnot p \lor (\lnot\lnot p\rightarrow p)$$ is true whenever $p$ is a finite union of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, but it is not intuitionistically valid.

Let $T$ be a finite union of open intervals. We'll call $T$ the *land* and $\lnot T$ (the interior of the complement of $T$) the *sea*. Any point of $\mathbb{R}$ which is not in the land or the sea is a boundary point of $T$. Let's say a boundary point $x$ is a *lake* if $x$ is isolated in the complement of $T$, and $x$ is a *beach* if not. For example, if $T = (a,b)\cup (b,c)$, then $a$ and $c$ are beaches and $b$ is a lake. Let $L$ be the set of lakes. Since $T$ is a finite union of intervals, $L$ is a finite discrete set.

Then $\lnot\lnot T$ is the interior of the complement of the sea. This contains the land and the lakes, but no beaches, so $\lnot\lnot T = T\cup L$.

Now $(\lnot\lnot T \rightarrow T)$ is the largest open set with the property that its intersection with $T\cup L$ is contained in $T$. In other words, it's all the points which have a neighborhood not containing any lakes. Since the lakes form a discrete set, $(\lnot\lnot T \rightarrow T) = \mathbb{R}\setminus L$.

Hence $\lnot\lnot T \lor (\lnot\lnot T\rightarrow T) = (T\cup L)\cup (\mathbb{R}\setminus L) = \mathbb{R}$.

I found this example by looking for the first place where the [free Heyting algebra on one generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra#/media/File:Rieger-Nishimura.svg) collapses when the generator is assigned to a generic finite union of intervals.

The argument above also goes through when $L$ has no limit points outside of $L$ (we didn't use that it's finite). So this formula is also valid on the algebra $\mathcal{H}'$ of (not necessarily finite) unions of open intervals with integer end points.

To come up with an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which does not satisfy this formula, we just need the lakes to have a limit point which is a beach (a limit of lakes can't be on land or in the sea). So let $U = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}_+} (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$. We have $\lnot\lnot U = (0,1)$ and $(\lnot\lnot U \rightarrow U) = \mathbb{R}\setminus (\{0\}\cup \{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}_+\})$, so $0\notin \lnot\lnot U \lor (\lnot\lnot U \rightarrow U)$.

Comment: +1, very nice!! I wonder if there's a snappy characterization of the sentences true whenever each propositional variable is interpreted as a finite union of open intervals (besides that, of course :P) . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber For formulas in 1 variable, the validities should be the validities of intuitionistic logic augmented by the axiom $\lnot\lnot p \lor (\lnot\lnot p \rightarrow p)$. To see this, look at the free Heyting algebra on one generator and note that all the entries in the first four rows are distinct when we take $p = (0,1)\cup (1,0)$, and in the fifth row $\lnot\lnot p \lor (\lnot\lnot p \rightarrow p) = 1$ and $(\lnot\lnot p \rightarrow p)\rightarrow (p\lor \lnot p) = \lnot p \lor \lnot\lnot p$ for finite unions of open intervals (and the latter equality follows from the new axiom).

Comment: But I have no idea about formulas in multiple variables!

Comment: Oops - I meant $p = (0,1)\cup (1,2)$, of course!